# eclipse BPEL designer case studies

Tags: eclipse, bpel

Are there any real world business process described in BPEL available ? I am using eclipse BPEL designer and apache ODE.

Thanks for any help,
Monika

Answer (score 0):

There are some good examples of real world business process in the following books:

- [Oracle SOA Suite 11g Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071608974)
- [Getting Started With Oracle SOA Suite 11g R1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184719978X)

Its for Oracle BPEL but it should not be difficult to re-create those in BPEL designer.